# The data fetch from pandas pivot table should be in normal font

Tags: pandas, excel, dataframe, pivot-table

I want to write a data frame to Excel. I have done it using pandas `pivot_table`. I have passed the column names as indexes. I am getting the excel, but it's in bold letters, I only need the column names as bold the values need to be in normal font.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a test df
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Name': ['ravi', 'Deepthy','ravi'],
                   'Ship': ['mount everes', 'mount everes', 'Oasis of the Seas'],  
                   'Tracking': ['TESTTRACK003', 'TESTTRACK008', 'TESTTRACK009'],
                    'Bag': ['123', '129', '129'],
    })

df=pd.pivot_table(df,values=["Name","Ship","Tracking","Bag"],
                  index=["Name","Ship","Tracking","Bag"])

def normal_font(_):
    return "font-weight: normal"

df.style.applymap_index(normal_font).to_excel("abcde.xlsx", engine="openpyxl",startrow=-1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`applymap_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap_index.html) with CSS [`font-weight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) property.

Try this :

```
def normal_font(_):
    return "font-weight: normal"

df.style.applymap_index(normal_font).to_excel("abcde.xlsx", engine="openpyxl",startrow=-1)
```

##### # Output (in Excel)

[image]

Comment: Showing one error like this 

AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'applymap_index'

Comment: You need to put my code right after this `df=pd.pivot_table`.. and make sure you're not using any styler before and also to restart your kernel if you're using a notebook. You're using `df.style` in your code/question and we don't know why. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how you're organyzing your code/script.

Comment: I will update the entire code again in my question. And I am using google collab for trying this

Comment: I just updatd . Please review it . Thank you for your support

Comment: Can you `print(pd.__version__)` ? To use `applymap_index`, you need at least pandas `1.4.0.`

Comment: My version is 1.3.5

Comment: Let me check the updated version

Comment: You can run `%pip install --upgrade pandas` in one of the cells of your colab.